# Video not loading in angular

Tags: html, angular

I am working on a project in angular, I have a component which should run a video in full screen and loop only once with autoplay, I tried to follow this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp).
But it the video is not working inside angular, I have the video in assets/videos folder.

This is my html

```
<video autoplay muted id="myVideo">
   <source src="/assets/videos/copro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
 </video>
</div>
```

This is the CSS I used

```
#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
```

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: try you refer this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-video-player-dawgzq

Comment: in ng serve you can't see with this path because asset folder way is not true. but in ng prod you will see it because when publish it asset folder will be there

Comment: can you share a stackblitz example of your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use prefix to see it. you need to write correct way. You says that your asset folder insede your component folder  same level with your html.

```
<source src="../../assets/videos/copro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: Can you tell me why is it not working after I reload the page, like after once it played I reloaded the page and the video is not seen, I even tried to restart the server it did not work, the video played only when I changed the path.  Where am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. just change the video URL in

data-ephox-embed-iri="https://youtu.be/"

src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" for embedded

```
<div style="left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; max-width: 1280px; max-height: 720px;" data-ephox-embed-iri="https://youtu.be/aYPaso1zHow"><iframe style="border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aYPaso1zHow?rel=0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: The thing is I want to add a video from my local system when I add an embed link it is working, I even tried by adding it drive and getting it from the link, it is not working!